# strange f# list notation in suave.io

Tags: f#, suave

In suave.io we can use `choose` combinator that has the `Types.WebPart list -> Types.WebPart` type.
Examples from their website show that I can use this combinator like this:

```
choose
    [ path "/hello" >>= OK "Hello GET"
      path "/goodbye" >>= OK "Good bye GET" ]
```

This list notation seems strange as it doesn't demand semicolon separating the elements. Yet, I have not been able to use it this way in different context. 
So the following works:

```
> choose
    [OK ""
     OK ""];;
val it : Types.WebPart = <fun:choose@47>'
```

as well as

```
> choose [OK "" ;OK ""];;
val it : Types.WebPart = <fun:choose@47>
```

But the following don't compile:

```
>choose [OK "" OK ""];; //ERROR
> [OK ""
  OK ""];; //ERROR
```

So, how does this notation work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your last example

```
[OK ""
OK ""]
```

you should see that the in last line: `OK ""` is not directly below the `OK` in the previous line: `[OK ""` (it's one of to the left)

This should give you a hint ;)

You *just* have to align the elements in the same column (recommended: just use spaces)

this is why you usually write

```
[
   OK ""
   OK ""
]
```

instead of beginning the first element after `[` - or some like

```
[ OK ""
; OK "" ]
```

too but I think that's not idiomatic F#.

#### remark

this also works with record syntax:

```
{
   surname = "Smith"
   givenname = "Adam"
}
```

Comment: I also found that there needs to be at least one space between bracket and an element.